# Submit Modal and run PHP script

Tags: php, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Bootstrap Modal, which I am just submitting and eventually it will send an email. For right now I am just trying to echo Signing Up.

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentform" method="post" action="signup.php">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Here Is my signup.php code:

```
<?php
echo "Signing Up";
?>
```

However, when I run this on my dreamhost server and press the Sign Up button, nothing happens at all. My console provides me with this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me as is (after adding a Submit button). See [demo](http://www.smartpage.me/so3.php)

Check your permissions on your files, make sure php files are 644 (-rw-r--r--)

Comment: From command line: chmod 644 *php   ... from dreamhost file manager there is probably a button to do it.

Comment: Checked on dreamhost, they are 644.

Comment: The exact same code on my host worked fine if you checked the source of my [demo](http://www.smartpage.me/so3.php). I'd check with your host.

Comment: Figured it out, I had my submit button in the footer rather than the actual form. Thanks, Guy.